# React Native Android get error after updated Android studio plugins MultipleCompilationErrorsException startup failed

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build

I'm working on React Native App using Android Studio.
Recently Android Studio ask me to make some updates so i click updated for some plugins ofr the IDE.

Now when i trie to build i got an error :

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
```

My project structure : 
[image: variables]
[image: project][image: Modules]

My build.grale content :

```
buildscript {
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 28
}
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1')
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

How can i fix the error when building :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fixed after doing this :

```
rm -rf node_modules

yarn   // install react native project dependencies 

yarn cache clean
```

delete the .idea project Android Studio

reopen the project in Android Studio and build again